# XHProf - View all profiles

Tags: php, profiling, profiler, xhprof

If I have it running all the time, I would like to be able to see all the profiles or see something that reflects all of the time.

The UI seems to require I specify a specific run, I would like to see them all, is that possible? Am I missing something very basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a GUI for XHProf that can help with this, it also does nice things like graph results over time: http://phpadvent.org/2010/profiling-with-xhgui-by-paul-reinheimer

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the @preinheimer XHProf UI implementation, you may as well want to give http://xhprof.io/ a try. The implementation relies on a set of libraries responsible for fetching, grouping and saving XHProf data. It is a lightweight, yet powerful implementation with a slick UI. The only warning is that, at the moment of this writing, it is in a beta state.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can register the xhprof save function using register_shutdown_function() to store the data and do some analyze later.

You can use some data visualize tools to help you, such as [highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/) and [d3js](http://d3js.org/).

And then you can get some thing like this:

[ddprof http://i.minus.com/icx2X7xtDwqMD.jpg](http://i.minus.com/icx2X7xtDwqMD.jpg)

This is a analyze system for my company so I can give out the code.

This DIY is easy and you can get the most flexibility.

But the easier way seems to using the above answers. ^_^